# What are the ontological prerequisites to make Lagrangian theories defineable?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, ontology

This question is a little strange, so stay with me. I understand that some physical theories apparently cannot be defined in terms of Lagrangians (although these generally are not fundamental theories), whereas some can. But this got me thinking about a related but different question - what are the necessary things we must posit to exist before we can even conceive of defining a Lagrangian theory?

To give an analogy, any theory within a Newtonian framework must take as primitive concepts a Euclidean space parameterised by time as an external variable, with some notion of mass. Whether a given theory obeys or fails to obey Newton's laws is only meaningful once we have these basic concepts, this basic ontology.

So what are the fundamental concepts and things to exist that are necessary for Lagrangian theories to be definable, even if a given theory may not have such a formulation?

Comment: Lagrangian theory can be derived from Newtonian theory, once you have defined energy.

Comment: But it is much more general, Lagrangian formulations exist for QM, QFT, GR, etc. Especially in the case of the standard model it seems to be a primitive notion from which other things are defined. As I stated explicitly, I only brought up Newtonian mechanics as an analogy.

Comment: The lageangian is an expression of the least action principle where energy and time are Fourier conjugates. Thus energy is a function that defines the system evolution in time.

Comment: You need a real variable called time and a set of real valued quantities whose values are differentiable functions of time.

Comment: One thing a lot of people overlook is that Lagrangian theories are fundamentally variational; that is, they assume the existence of something (the action) that nature automatically minimizes. Not many know that you can actually formulate constraints on physical systems at least mathematically that cause the variational/Lagrangian picture to fail!

Comment: Does the "set of real valued quantities" need only be functions of time, or do they need to be functions of space too? Do we even need a notion of space? Do these quantities need to be related to one another? And once we have these quantities, what would you need to do with them to make an arbitrary Lagrangian (accepting that it is also possible to make physical theories that can't be expressed in a Lagrangian formalism)?